# What are possible type arguments for generic types?

Tags: java, generics

I am starting use Java generic. I have a Parameter interface and its ParameterImpl   concrete class. The T will be a Float, Long, Integer or String.

```
public interface Parameter<T extends Comparable<T>>  {}  
public class ParameterImpl<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Parameter<T> {}
```

In other classes, saying `public class A` and `public class B`:

1. class variable of type **Parameter** can be declared as: `Parameter parameter` or `Parameter<?> parameter` but not `Parameter <T> parameter`.

   ```
   //warning, should be parameterized
   Parameter p;
   //no warning
   Parameter<?> p2;
   //error
   Parameter<T> p3;
   //warning, should be parameterized
   Map<String, Parameter> pMap;
   //no warning
   Map<String, Parameter<?>> pMap2;
   //error
   Map<String, Parameter<T>> pMap3;
   ```

Then should I use the **Wildcard** everywhere when asked? or just ignore the warning and use the non-parameterized version?

2. there are three options for the methods:

   ```
       public <T extends Comparable<T>> Parameter<T> getParameter2(Map<String, Parameter<T>> map, String key) { return null; }

        public Parameter <?> getParameter (Map<String, Parameter<?>> map, String key){ return null; }

       public Parameter getParameter3(Map<String, Parameter> map, String key) { return null; }
   ```

similar as the class variable cases, the last one has warning about the parameterized. Which way I should go?

Comment: Use the `?` wildcard only when you _really don't care about the type_ at runtime.  If you find yourself using it a lot, go back and rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the concrete type such as:

```
Parameter<Long> p2 = ...;
```

Your method will then be:

```
public Parameter<T> getParameter3(Map<String, Parameter<T>> map, String key) { return null; }
```

or if you require a more specific version

```
public Parameter<Long> getParameter3(Map<String, Parameter<Long>> map, String key) { return null; }
```

The wildcard is used then it could be *any* type i.e. when you write a very general function or declare a very general parameter. You could also use *bounded wildcards* which forces you to inherit from e.g. `Number` such as this:

```
Paremeter<? extends Number> numberedParameter;
```

Comment: public Parameter<T> getParameter3(Map<String, Parameter<T>> map, String key) { return null ;} will get compile error. We have to have  <T extends Comparable<T>>  after the public key word. Because this method is NOT in a generic class.

Comment: well, there you go - use an appropriate typing and in your case I guess you have already figured it out. Don't use the wildcard `<?>` unless that is *what you need*.

Answer (score 0):

Your type `Parameter` is generic.

This

```
Parameter p;
```

is using `Parameter` as a raw type. [Avoid using it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

This

```
//no warning
Parameter<?> p2;
```

is using `Parameter` with a type argument of `?`, the wildcard. You can assign any value of type `Parameter` to the variable `p2`, regardless of its parameterization.

This

```
//error
Parameter<T> p3;
```

is attempting to use a type named `T` as a type argument to `Parameter`. If such a type doesn't exist or isn't in scope, a compiler error will occur. That's what seems to be happening.

> Then should I use the Wildcard everywhere when asked?

No, use an *appropriate* type argument. This depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I think I understand the class variable case now. How about the Map cases? The Parameter in a map is mixed, some are Long and some are Float and others. Then it is the right place for wildcard? I don't want to make Class A or Class B a generic type.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA I don't understand your question. Generics are _generic_. You can apply them to the type(s) you need. If you don't care what that type is, you can use a wildcard. If you want to apply restrictions on the types you apply type bounds.